# Data dependent tests

Tags: java, mysql, testing, vert.x

I`m writing test for my "MySQL Requests Manager" and the problem is that some of the tests is depends on the data that contained in the database. So if any other test will delete the required records or someone else will delete them, that means that test will fail even if they correct.

I`m thinking about two approaches here:
1. In the test itself backup all the needed data before, run the test and restore the data from backup. But this is much more error prone and "heavier", in my humble opinion.
2. Before running one of the tests or even all of them is to create whole new database with structure and required data (from previously made dump, i think). This involves only around of two 'global' actions: create database and dropping it. Of course, i need to have totally isolated MySQL user and database for this.

What you think and what can you recommend? How another programmers dealing with that kind of issue?

Comment: I'd vote for 2. Isolation is always good thing to have. You can sleep soundly knowing your tests are not gonna mess with your actual data.

Comment: google for "integration tests"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different idea if you want to check it out: there's a java framework [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org) that is pretty helpful in cases like this. With it, you can create 'Mock' instantiations of certain objects/services that allow you to avoid actually instantiating them. With a mock, you can return a custom/hard coded results and test that your service handles that response correctly. For example, say you have a class 'SQLTestService' that has a method called 'getData()'. You can instantiate a Mock of 'SQLTestService' and have it return a specific value when 'getData()' is called. That way your tests are never actually dependent on the data in the DB and you can test for a specific outcome that you know your service should be able to handle.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion! But i am also testing usual MySQL request that i do with vert.x so its critical for me to work with the actual data. So the services that uses this requests need to work with the actual data. P.S.: I hope you get my point, it might be unclear because of my English :)

Answer (score 0):

When writing unit test, one should:

- Use a test DB
- Load data before each test (or load data before all tests)

```java
@Before 
public void setUp() {
  //insert your test data here
}
```

- Drop data after each test (or drop data after all tests)

```java
@After
public void tearDown() {
 // drop your test data here
}
```

That means the DB is system independent and each test runs isolated without having the fear of losing data, or interference between tests.